# How at a time one row can expand in <p:dataTable>?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

In my application I have a `<p:datatable>` with `rowExpansion` column. I have a requirement to open a single row at a time. If anyone tries to expand second row, remaining first row expanded then one message will be generated saying `First close the expanded row and then open another row`.

How this can be implemented ? Any pointer will be very helpful to me. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use (I have tested it in mojarra 2.1.20 and Primefaces 3.5 and it works fine) the following solution which calls a JavaScript function when the row is expanded.  When clicking on a second row, and there is another expanded row, it will trigger a `click` event, which will in turn collapse the previously opened row.

#### xhtml:

```xml
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" onstart="test();"/>
```

#### Javascript:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        var i = $('.ui-row-toggler.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s').length;
        if(i == 1){return;}
            $('.ui-row-toggler.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s').trigger('click');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: But I am facing another problem : when I expand second row remaining first row expanded then after firing second row's toggle event, first row's toggle event is firing. So in backing bean I am getting the first row's information rather than the second row's information. How I collapse the expanded row first and then expand the second row?..

Comment: You get the second row's information first,alter you get the first row's information. You can debug to see that :)

Comment: yes you are right, but I want to get the information from bean about that row which remains currently expanded. in this case from backing bean I am getting the first row's information as last toggled row. It will be better if first collapse another expanded row, then expand the current row. Is it possible/

Comment: Sorry, you get the second row's information first,after that you get the first row's information.

Comment: Yes, because first expand second row then collapse first row so I get the second row's information after that get first row's(`collapse`) information.

Comment: So why you want to collapse the expanded row first and then expand the second row?

Comment: From bean I want to edit and save the currently expanded row's data. Now when i expand second row, in bean I have first row's information `ActivityDTO tempActivityDTO = (ActivityDTO) event.getData();` But I need second row's info.

Comment: You can use count variable to get the target you want, did you try :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28191/discussion-between-rongnk-and-diganta)

Comment: Till now I am suffering this problem. because taking static variable is not safe when multiple user from different PC access the application.

Comment: so how I should implement with out static variable

Comment: I don't know your system design, you can use session variable, or use variable with session scope.

Comment: If my bean is in session scope, then when multiple users access the bean, All of them will access the same static variable declared in that bean or not?

Comment: No, can not same, each user has private session(one or many).

Comment: Actually I have forgotten to mark your answer correct, As this answer helps me so I select this answer as correct answer. Thanks @ RongNK for your help.

Answer (score 9):

As of 2015, and this question is first in Google search results, I want to add that for PrimeFaces 5.1, there is dataTable attribute `rowExpandMode`, when set to `single` - allows only one row to be shown. Example:

```
<p:dataTable var="line" value="#{bean.lines}" rowExpandMode="single">
```

It's not exactly what was asked, but I hope that it'll help to others.

Comment: It definitely helped. We recently moved from 5.0 to 5.1 and I didn't know that. It worked.

Comment: This was the key for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `datatable.js` file in Primefaces [here](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js). There is a javascript function called `toggleExpansion`.

Maybe you can override this function and call the original one when no row is expanded and show a message when another row is already expanded (and not call the original one).

Just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with the help of this custom method.

give 'togglerClass' this class like

```
 <pou:column styleClass="togglerClass" style="width:16px">
                                            <pou:rowToggler/>
                                        </pou:column>
```

JavaScript code here;

```
function prodsToggler() {
    $('.togglerClass div').click(function () {
        var currentTr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var $trs = $('.togglerClass').closest("tr").not(currentTr);
        $trs.each(function (index, el) {
            var $this = $(el),
                    $next = $this.next(".ui-expanded-row-content");

            $this.removeClass("ui-expanded-row");
            $next.remove();

            $this.find(".ui-row-toggler").removeClass("ui-icon-circle-triangle-s");
        });
    });
}
```

call this method in windows ready.