# expanded row should be collapse on selection of anotherrow

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.3 and using p:rowExpansion with p:toggler under a datatable.
I want to collapse the previously expanded row on selection of the other row.

I have one datatable with id reconcileTable.

Do we have any feature in primefaces to handle this situation?

thanks in advance!

Code Snippet::

```
 <p:dataTable id="ux_reconciliation_table" widgetVar="reconcileTable">                                   

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{reconciliationBean.validateReconciliationAction}" update=":reconciliation_form:multiProcessBtn,:message_form_dialog :reconciliation_form:removeLatestSel" oncomplete="checkRowExpansion()"></p:ajax>
    <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{reconciliationBean.onRowToggle}" update="ux_row_nonrequired_content "/>
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":reconciliation_form:multiProcessBtn"/>

    <f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputPanel>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{resourceBundle['reconciliation.worksheet_search.label']} " styleClass="ux_reconciliation_datatable_header_text"/>
    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="reconcileTable.filter()" styleClass="ux_reconciliation_input_search_field" />
    <h:graphicImage value="../images/common/I_Search.png" styleClass="ux_dialog_search"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>

    <p:column id="Billing_MiscParty_PartyRole_Party_Organization_NameInfo_longName" sortBy="#{reconciliationDetail.payorName}" filterBy="#{reconciliationDetail.payorName}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyleClass="hide" styleClass="ux_ui-datatable-column ux_alpha-column">  
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="" styleClass="ux_title_table_header_reconcile"/><br/>
    <h:outputText value="#{resourceBundle['reconciliation.payor_insured.table.column']}" styleClass="ux_title_table_header_reconcile"/><br/>
</f:facet>  
<h:panelGroup id="reconArrowTogglerLink">   
<div class="#{reconciliationDetail.parentId == 0?'ux_reconciliation_togger_icon':'ux_reconciliation_togger_icon ux_tab_style'}" onclick="reconciliationDatatable.onRowToggle(this, reconcileTable);">                                
    <p:rowToggler/>
    </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText styleClass="ux_column_data_text ux_normal_text ux_reconciliation_subcriber" rendered="#{reconciliationDetail.payorName != null}" value="#{reconciliationDetail.payorName}"/>

    </p:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is when user expan one row, other expanded row will trigger click event and it will be collapsed.

**See also:** [How at a time one row can expand in ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972990/how-at-a-time-one-row-can-expand-in-pdatatable/15975948#15975948)

In OnRowSelection, you just set `selectionMode="single"`(Datatable's attribute)

Comment: Thanks RongNK...Its working fine with on toggle..i want same thing on row selection....i tried same thing with onSelect event, but its not working :(

Comment: Did you set selectionMode="single"(i have updated my answer) ?

Comment: As per the requirement i set selectionMode="multiple" and user can select multiple record.

Comment: "user can select multiple record", so what do you mean "selected row should be unselect on selection of anotherrow" ?

Comment: If you set selectionMode="multiple", so user have to press Ctrl key, if user want to select one row, user just release Ctrl key !

Comment: @RongNK...the issue is not with multiple row selection..the problem is that if one row is expaned than on selection of other row the expaned row should be collpase...currently it's not happening :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28748/discussion-between-rongnk-and-vikas)

Comment: Oh, i have just try with PF 3.4.2, the problem may be your icon is too small, so when you think you click on toggle icon, in fact you click on row, so it will not work !

Comment: oh,do we have any work around to make it work for me for row selection?

Comment: You shoudl record one video then send to me: khacrong@gmail.com :)