# PrimeFaces expand row on row click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have [RowExpansion](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml) dataTable

```
<p:dataTable value="#{clients.clients}" var="client">
   <p:column>
      <p:rowToggler  />
   </p:column>

   <p:column headerText="name" sortBy="#{client.name}">
      <h:outputText value="#{client.name}"/>
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="email" sortBy="#{client.email}">
      <h:outputText value="#{client.email}" />
   </p:column>

   <p:rowExpansion>
      <p:panelGrid  columns="2">
         <h:outputText value="Id:" />
         <h:outputText value="#{client.id}" />
      </p:panelGrid>
   </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

And I need to do two things:

1. Expand row on row click
2. Hide previous expanded rows.

So how to do this?

Comment: As for primefaces 5.1 here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972990/how-at-a-time-one-row-can-expand-in-pdatatable/29730152#29730152

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the `togglerSelector` event to `tr` instead of the icon.

You can see this clearly in the [`bindExpansionEvents`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/0566f53e5d5edfaf737c783e4d9dcd6a16362b07/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L550) function, the current `togglerSelector` is `> tr > td > div.ui-row-toggler` all you have to do is bind the same event to `>tr`, and of course before expanding the clicked row, you collapse all the expanded rows by calling [collapseAllRows()](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/0566f53e5d5edfaf737c783e4d9dcd6a16362b07/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L1478).

Here's a full example:

```
function rowExpansion(dataTable) {
   //dataTable should be the widgetVar object
   var $this = dataTable;
   //add the 'hand' when hovering on row
   $this.tbody.children('tr').css('cursor', 'pointer')
   $this.tbody.off('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr')
      .on('click.datatable-expansion', '> tr', null, function() {
         //before expanding collapse all rows
         $this.collapseAllRows();
         //toggle the current row the old toggler
         $this.toggleExpansion($(this).find('div.ui-row-toggler'));
       });
 }
```

Then simply call it in the `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   rowExpansion(PF('dataTableWV'));// if you are using PF 3.5 or lower pass the the object without PF() shortcut
});
```

See: [online demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/rowExpansion/main.xhtml)

Comment: Hello i got this
Widget for var 'dataTableWV' not available!                <p:dataTable tableStyleClass="dispo" var="element"  
                                 id="tablaItinerario" value="#{disponibilidadBean.listadoItinerario}"
                                 selectionMode="single"  rowExpandMode="single" rowIndexVar="cont"  widgetVar="dataTableWV"
                                 selection="#{disponibilidadBean.registroItinerario}" rowKey="#{element.codigo}"   >

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented the solution of @Hatem Aliman in Primefaces 5.1 and it works fine so far.

If you enabled `rowExpandMode="single"`, you don't need to close the opened rows by yourself. Just comment out the row: `$this.collapseAllRows();`