# How to expand one row at a time in nested PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0 and I want to expand one row at a time and other rows should be collapsed.  I have a requirement to open a single row at a time. I have seen solution for the same question but when I am trying to implement that on a data table inside a data table , it is collapsing the parent datable also....I need to collapse only child table inside parent data table.

Comment: I posted your title in Google and found a duplicate... easy to do yourself. It should even have been shown when you were typing your title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How at a time one row can expand in <p:dataTable>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972990/how-at-a-time-one-row-can-expand-in-pdatatable)

Comment: that doesn't work in my case...plz help me out for this.

Comment: 'doesn't work... meaning? Blows up your computer? Please be waaaay more specific in what happens, why it fails etc.